# How do you work with spells in homebrew subclasses on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, dnd-beyond

I'm trying to create a homebrew subclass on D&D Beyond, but I can't seem to figure out how to make spells work. There are different places for an added list of spells and actually adding spells, there's no option for making spells always prepared or not, etc.

Can someone who has more experience with D&D Beyond tell me how exactly this all works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You need to do this as part of a feature

The spell options on the subclass itself is, as far as I know, only a meta description of the spellcasting capacities. The actual programming of the subclass is done as part of the features.

To add spells which are always prepared, make a feature. On any feature, you can add spells and set some options for them. You can eg. modify the range or cast time, and importantly specify whether it consumes a spell slot, counts as a known spell, always prepared, and at what level it is added.

Note that if you are making a subclass for a class which has a general type for subclass spell list (ie. all subclasses have a list of spells added which work the same way; Cleric, Paladin, Warlock), you don't have to do this, you can simply add them to the "Additional Specific Spells" field and they should work the same way as the other subclasses. As a tip, you can create a subclass as a copy of an existing one, which gives you an example to look at for how things are implemented.

Comment: Worth noting that the official classes and subclasses world this way too: spellcasting is always defined by a class feature.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Are you referring to the official publication (text) or the D&D Beyond implementation?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, the published rules. It’s worth mentioning because having the conceptual structure of classes clear in one’s head makes using the tool easier.